# Error "Can't implicitly convert int to short" when substracting integers in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and apologize for asking this, possibly stupid question. But, I can't find the answer. Why I get this below error when substracting to integers?

```
        Console.WriteLine(num2.GetType()); // System.Int16
        Console.WriteLine(num1.GetType()); // System.Int16
        num2 = num1 - num2;
```

"num1 - num2" get red underline and it says "Can't implicitly convert int to short"

What is the problem here?

Comment: VS assumes int16 - int16 produces a int32 so you must cast the subtraction back to a short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It becomes clearer if you add an extra line to your code without the erroring line

```
short num1 = 2;
short num2 = 4;
Console.WriteLine(num2.GetType()); // System.Int16
Console.WriteLine(num1.GetType()); // System.Int16
Console.WriteLine( (num1 - num2).GetType()); // System.Int32
```

As you can see, subtracting a Int16 from another Int16 actally gives an Int32. You can't assign (without an explicit cast) the result back to `num2` as it is defined as an Int16.

Solve it using an explicit cast if you *really* want to assign back to `num2`

```
num2 = (short)(num1-num2);
```

Comment: Now it's clear why that happens. Thanks a lot for helping with that!

Answer (score 2):

Both variables are `short` (System.Int16), but when doing arithmetic, the result will be `int` (System.Int32), and C# won't assign an `int` to `short` implicitly ("Can't implicitly convert int to short"), because it may lead to loss.

To fix, make the conversion explicit:

```
num2 = (short)(num1 - num2);
```